# Angular2- Is there a way to check if object resource has more than ... letters?

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to check is `result.resource.display_name` has more than x letters than change styling of the element but how can I check this?

first I checked by `result.object.reference` if it is bigger than 100 than set styling but I want to check the count of letters of the `display_name`

```
<sebm-google-map-info-box #infowindow [alignBottom]="true" [style.width.px]="result.resource.display_name.length >= 5 ? 250 : 200">
      <span class="tooltip-id">
          {{ result.object.reference }}
      </span>
      <span class="tooltip-data">
           {{ result.resource.display_name }}
      </span>
</sebm-google-map-info-box>
```

This is not working it always sets its width to 200px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use style binding like

```
<div [style.text-overflow]="result.resource.display_name.length > 20 ? 'ellipsis' : 'none'">{{result.resource.display_name}}</div>
```

`ngStyle` can be used similarly or `[class.wide]="..."` to add/remove a class depending on the result

Comment: Edited my question :)

Comment: `[style.width.px]="result.resource.display_name.length > 20 ? 100 : 50"`

Comment: it sets its width always to the else width

Comment: Try adding `{{result.resource.display_name.length}}` somewhere in your template to see what value it returns.

Comment: smallest is 7 and largest 19. But I think it is not possible to set it on the component because the width is set on the class  `marker-tooltip`

Comment: So where is the surprise? ;-) You check `length >= 5 `

Comment: so every infowindow should be 250px?

Comment: is it possible to do this: `[.marker.style.widt.px]`?

Comment: You mean apply it to some other element? No. That only works on the element where it is added.

Comment: hmm I think thats the problem: because the width is applied on the .marker-tooltip class

Comment: You can use `[class.someClass]="..."` to set a class and then you can use styles like `.someClass .marker { width: 200px; }` (when the marker is a child of the element where you add `[class.someClass]="..."`)

Comment: Sorry, have to leave. Wife needs me. I thought I just did. Add/remove a class and use CSS to style a child depending on that class.

Comment: ` boxClass: string = "marker-tooltip";
    boxStyle: mapTypes.BoxStyle = { background:'', opacity: 1, width: "" };` this is set in the directive.

Comment: is it possible to do this: `[boxStyle.width]="result.resource.display_name.length >= 10 ? 500 : 50"`

Comment: What is `boxStyle`?

Comment: /**
     * An object literal whose properties define specific CSS style values to be applied to the InfoBox.
     * Style values defined here override those that may be defined in the boxClass style sheet.
     * If this property is changed after the InfoBox has been created, all previously set styles (except those defined in the style sheet)
     * are removed from the InfoBox before the new style values are applied.
     */
    boxStyle: mapTypes.BoxStyle = { background:'', opacity: 1, width: "" };

Comment: Sorry I don't know this Google maps stuff at all. `[boxStyle.width]="..."` is not valid anyway.